# Upper bound on P(S_n > a) by mgf, Strong Law Large Numbers Proof Casella, Berger

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, statistics, moment-generating-functions, law-of-large-numbers

Having trouble coming up with a proof for a problem related to SLLN using MGFS. I found [Strong Law of Numbers for $S_{n}$ Bounded Casella Berger 5.38](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234875/strong-law-of-numbers-for-s-n-bounded-casella-berger-5-38) but the answer doesn't seem to hint at how we could establish some lower bound. I've put my effort below, but *it feels cheap*, are there other methods in which I can approach this problem?

Problem statement: 
Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid random variables with mgf $M_X(t),-h<t<h$, let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}S_n$

I've already via Markov inequality shown that $$P(S_n>a)\le e^{-at}[M_X(t)]^n$$
and
$$P(S_n \le a) \le e^{-at}[M_X(t)]^n$$
Now we must prove that for $E[X]<0$ and $M_X(0)=1$ there exists $0<c<1$ s.t $P(S_n>a) \le c^n$.

Now my first instinct is to use a Taylor expansion:

$$M_X(t) \approx M_X(0) + M_X'(0)t =1 + tE[X]$$

However I can only see this bringing us to the upperbound in the link mentioned earlier: 
$$M_X(t) \le 1 + t\frac{E[X]}{2} \le 1$$
Since $E[X]$ is negative, or the second derivative of the mgf is negative near 0. Taking t=0 gives us the 1 as the final upperbound. The nth power of the mgf retains the property of 1 as an upperbound. Since we are confident of the upper-bound on $M_X(t)$ in the neighbourhood of 0 couldn't we just use:

$$P(S_n>a) \le c^n = \left[ e^{-at/n}*M_X(t) \right]^n?$$

We've shown that from $E[X]<0$, $M_X(t)$ is bounded above by 1 in the neighbourhood of 0. In addition as n grows, since $0<c<1$, then $0<c^n<1$. Am I missing something here? I should note that nothing about the nature of $a$ is given, I assumed it was positive above.

Hints would be appreciated, my analysis skill-set is limited and something I'm working on!