# How does this answer establish this inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I read an answer posted on this site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234875/strong-law-of-numbers-for-s-n-bounded-casella-berger-5-38?noredirect=1)

To save you the time of reading that post, the answer claims that if a function $f(t)$ is a continuous function with negative derivative at $0$, we can find a $t$ close to zero such that

$$f(t) - f(0) \leq \frac{t}{2} f'(0)$$

I have two problems understanding this:

1. In the question, $f(t)$ is the moment generating function $M_X (t)$ of a random variable $X$. How do we know it is continuous? I don't see how the definition of $M_X (t)$ establishes continuity.
2. How does he establish that inequality? I tried writing out the Taylor expansion of $f(t)$ at $t$ centred around $0$, but I don't see where he gets the $\frac{1}{2}$ from, which is necessary to the proof.

Any help in understanding this inequality is appreciated.

Comment: Why not ask the user who posted the solution in the first place?

Comment: The inequality is suspcious also why we have $\dfrac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}\le c f'(0)$ for any constant $c$ ($t\to 0$)?

Comment: Its 1 year and 5 months old. I feel opening a new question is more productive.

Comment: I think the original answer is supposed to use the Taylor expansion of the moment generating function around $0$ to establish this inequality. If we can establish $M_X (t) \leq M_X (0) + t M'_X(0)$ the result is finished, since $M_X (0)=1$ and $M'_X (0) < 0$. I'm not sure how to establish that though. The remaining $M''_X (0)$ in the Taylor expansion is positive, being a second moment, so how do we establish that upper bound

Comment: The only other thing that occurs to me, is the original question actually has an extra $e^{-at}$ term. So if we can show $e^{-at} M_X(t) \leq c$ for $c<1$ then we are also done, rather than just using $M_X (t)$ itself

Comment: If $f'(0)<0$ then $f'(0)/2>f'(0) = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}$ so indeed for all  $t> 0$ that are sufficiently close to 0, we have $f'(0)/2 \geq \frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}$.

Comment: That makes sense @Michael thanks a lot!

Comment: Every MGF is continuous on the interval around 0 where it is finite. Hint: Dominated convergence.